# 'move cell up' not updating properly in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having issues with re-arranging the cells in my tableView in edit mode. Moving the cell down works fine, but moving the cell up reeks havoc on the order. Sometimes it goes back to it's normal position, other times it chooses a random spot to end up. Ironically, the Core data model and order end up correctly each time.

I've searched through STO and really haven't found a solution.

-There are no gesture controls applied, I've tried disabling them as well.

-Tried [self setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:NO];

-Tried [self.tableView.canCancelContentTouches = NO];

-NSFetchControls/delegates bypassed with BOOL

Code I'm using to move the cells is basically same as:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[_tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
if(editing) {
    NSInteger rowsInSection = [self tableView:_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
   // Update the position of all items
   for (NSInteger i=0; i<rowsInSection; i++) {
      NSIndexPath *curIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
      SomeManagedObject *curObj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:curIndexPath];
      NSNumber *newPosition = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:i];
      if (![curObj.displayOrder isEqualToNumber:newPosition]) {
         curObj.displayOrder = newPosition;
      }
   }
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSInteger moveDirection = 1;
    NSIndexPath *lowerIndexPath = toIndexPath;
    NSIndexPath *higherIndexPath = fromIndexPath;
    if (fromIndexPath.row < toIndexPath.row) {
    // Move items one position upwards
    moveDirection = -1;
    lowerIndexPath = fromIndexPath;
    higherIndexPath = toIndexPath;
}

// Move all items between fromIndexPath and toIndexPath upwards or downwards by one position
for (NSInteger i=lowerIndexPath.row; i<=higherIndexPath.row; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *curIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:fromIndexPath.section];
    SomeManagedObject *curObj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:curIndexPath];
    NSNumber *newPosition = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:i+moveDirection];
    curObj.displayOrder = newPosition;
}

SomeManagedObject *movedObj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
movedObj.displayOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:toIndexPath.row];
NSError *error;

if (![_fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not save context: %@", error);
} else {
   [self.tableview reloadData];
}
}
```

Hope someone can answer this one, because people that answer STO questions are just awesome! :) Thanks in advance!!!

-UPDATE-

I found that when I move the cells up the method keeps referencing the same object and updating it to new order, instead of updating the next object with the new order.

ie. Move cell up - Results = (Object1.order = 1, Object1.order = 2, Object1.order = 3)

ie. Move cell down - Results = (Object1.order = 1, Object2.order = 2, Object3.order = 0)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (NSInteger i=lowerIndexPath.row; i<=higherIndexPath.row; i++)
```

to

```
for (NSInteger i=fromIndexPath.row; i<=toIndexPath.row; i -= moveDirection)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it didn't make a difference for me, maybe it will for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous things, I resorted back to apple docs way of doing it. For anyone else having same problems as me, create a mutablecopy of the NSArray you get from your coreData and use apple docs way of inserting and removing from index. It seemed to fix the problem for me. :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html